# Google Spreadsheets importxml adding unwanted "breaks" in text

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the `IMPORTXML` function with Google Spreadsheets. I am able to get the content that I want in the cell I want but the text gets imported with seemingly random line breaks.

**Example:**

In cell **A2** I have the URL: http://www.ford.com/cars/fusion/incentives/

In cell **B2** I have `=Concatenate(IMPORTXML(A2,"//div[@class='incentives_header']"))`

**What gets pulled is:**

"Pricing / Incentives and OffersFind the latest purchase or leasing offers for your next Ford vehicle, Ford /* Unwanted Line Break Here */

Credit financing options and other details to discuss with your local Ford 
Dealer./* No Space After the period*/Special Programs/*Should be a line break here. "Special Programs" is an h2 */Explore special program offers for qualified buyers with your life 
experiences."

**What it should look like is:**

Pricing / Incentives and Offers
Find the latest purchase or leasing offers for your next Ford vehicle, Ford Credit financing options and other details to discuss with your local Ford Dealer.
Special Programs
Explore special program offers for qualified buyers with your life experiences.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

=substitute(substitute(regexreplace(B2,"\n",""),",",char(10)),".",char(10))